# writeFile() method not working

Tags: java, arraylist, writefile

I am trying to write to a text file. I am able to write to the console however, i am not able to write to my text file. One thing i have noticed is that `String data` doesn't contain any data if i were to just print to the console which is probably why nothing appears in my textfile. Does anyone know why that is though and how i can come about it?

**writeFile() method code:**

```
public static void writeFile(String filename, String content) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            Files.write(Paths.get(filename), content.getBytes()); // write file
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error writing file: " + e);
        }
    }
```

**Test code:**

```
public class QuickTest {
    public static void main(String... p) throws IOException {

        List<SensorInfo> readings = new ArrayList<>();
        SensorInfo info = null;

        String data = createStringFromInfo(readings);
        writeFile("datastore.txt", data);

        String filedata = readFile("client-temp.txt");

        List<SensorInfo> temps = createInfoFromData(filedata);

        System.out.println(header());

        for (SensorInfo reading : temps) {
            System.out.print(reading.display());

        }


    }

}
```

**CreateFromInfo Method:**

```
public static String createStringFromInfo(List<SensorInfo> infoList)
    {
        String data = "";
        for (SensorInfo info : infoList)
        {
            data += info.asData();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

**createInfoFromData**

```
public static List<SensorInfo> createInfoFromData(String data)
    {
        List<SensorInfo> infoList = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] lines = data.split("\n");

        for (String line : lines)
        {
            SensorInfo info = new SensorInfo(line);
            infoList.add(info);
        }

        return infoList;
    }
```

Comment: We would need to see the `createStringFromInfo()` method to be sure why `data` contains no data, but my first guess would be that it's because you're passing an empty list to that method.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Please find the createStringFromInfo() method written above.

Comment: You create a new `ArrayList` and then read its content. Where should the data come from?

Comment: @Tom The data is coming from "client-temp.txt"

Comment: @rr0102 No. You read that file *after* you're trying to write to `datastore.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

That implementation of `createStringFromInfo()` confirms my guess: it will return an empty string when its argument is an empty list, as is the case in your program.  I agree with you that that is why you get an empty file.

You fix it by filling the `readings` list with `SensorInfo` objects describing the information you want written to the file (before you invoke `createStringFromInfo()`).  If the data for those `SensorInfo` objects should come from reading file "client-temp.txt" then you should read it in first, then pass *that* `List` to `createStringFromInfo()` to get the data to write.

Comment: yes the data comes from reading the file "client-temp.txt". I have read it in first and then past that list to createStringFromInfo() and it seems to still produce an empty text file

Comment: Does reading the file in fact produce any `SensorInfo` objects?  Does `SensorInfo.asData()` produce a non-empty `String`?  Is the `String` returned by `createStringFromInfo()` the one you are passing to `writeFile()`?  Your program is probably falling down in one of these places.

Comment: when i print out the array list after reading in the file, it prints an empty array. And i've also tried print 'data' and that produces nothing

Comment: I don't know exactly what you means when you say you "print out the array list", but if the `List` you pass to `createStringFromInfo()` is empty then the result is an empty `String`.  If you pass an empty `String` to your `writeFile()` method then you get an empty file.  Does `createInfoFromData()` work correctly?  Is there any data in `client-temp.txt` for it to read?

Comment: apologies for my unclear explanation. What i meant was if i did System.out.println(readings) or System.out.println(data) i get empty strings. I will attach the createInfoFromData() method above. And yes there is data in the text file for it to read.

Comment: @rr0102 Can you explain why you think that these variables (`readings` and `data`) should be something else than "empty"? You're not even assigning the data from your text file to these variables.

Comment: readings and data shouldn't be empty as they should contain data from the text file. I thought that i had assigned those variables through List<SensorInfo> readings = new ArrayList<>() and String data = createStringFromInfo(readings). But from what you have just said, i haven't. What would you advice me to do in order to carry out these assignments?

Comment: @rr0102 it should be enough if look at your `main` method and read out loud what you're doing there. You should be able to see, that the chronological order of your method calls doesn't make sense, if `readings` should contain the data from `"client-temp.txt"`.

Comment: Yes, `List<SensorInfo> readings = new ArrayList<>()` assigns a value to variable `readings`.  *That value is an empty List*.  Nothing in the program as you presented it adds any elements to it.